# How to fetch the unmapped records in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL database and my table structure is as like:

```
+---------------+----------------+-------------------+
| leave_type_id | leave_type     | leave_type_org_id |
+---------------+----------------+-------------------+
|            23 | Casual Leave   |                33 | 
|            24 | Earn Leave     |                 0 | 
|            33 | Sick Leave     |                 0 | 
|            34 | CL   Leave     |                 0 | 
|            35 | PL   LEAVE     |                23 | 
|            42 | EL   LEAVE     |                 0 | 
+---------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

and i want to fetch only the unmapped records from my table leave_type, mean which leave_type_id is not present inside the leave_type_org_id like (24, 34, 35, 42) plz send me the query as in reply asap.
Thanks.

Comment: This is not properly formated, and a malformed question. Can you please format this with "code" tags so that we can read this?

Comment: Hey,I don't know how to format in stack over flow can give me the hints of it plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do join on same table like this

```
select t1.* 
from table t1
left join table t2
on t1.leave_type= t2.leave_type_org_id
where t2.leave_type_org_id is null
```

OR

With sub query

```
select * from table 
where leave_type_id not in 
(
    select leave_type_org_id from table  
)
```

Comment: Hey Buddy i don't have more than one table that is a single table so we don't required to apply join here.

Comment: @subodh: join can be applied on single table and in above query there is only single table. The above condition either require join or sub query. Try above query

Comment: Hey,I don't know why the above query is not working but in the place of sub query if i put any static values then it will work fine. and also one by one query is working fine.

Comment: @subodh: Both queries will work there is nothing wrong with them you are doing something wrong. You need to change `table` to your actual table name

Comment: @subodh: Please accept the answer If it helped you. You can click on the right arrow sign.